# Ionic GeoPosition TypeError

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using the Ionic Framework for an app I am creating and got stopped by this. I'm using the [Geolocation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/) module to get the user's current position. I have an object that stores the latitude and longitude as so:

```
location_coordinate: {
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;
}
```

But when I try to save the latitude and longitude to my object (`this.location_coordinate.latitude = resp.coords.latitude;`) this doesn't work and an error is thrown.

`Error getting location TypeError: Cannot set property 'latitude' of undefined`

If I set it to a variable, for example:

```
latitude: number;
```

And then:

```
this.lat = resp.coords.latitude;
```

This works. Why is this so? Am I missing something?

*Note: The* `resp.coords.latitude` *is what is returned from the get request.*

Answer (score 0):

`Error getting location TypeError: Cannot set property 'latitude' of undefined`.

This error probably means `location_coordinate` is `undefined`. Check the code where you have defined [or maybe never defined?] `this.location_coordinate`. Once this is set to some object, you should definitely be able to use `this.location_coordinate.latitude = resp.coords.latitude;`

In order to validate my hypothesis, you can do following:

1. Assign a constant instead to see if error persists: `this.location_coordinate.latitude = 0;`
2. Print the value of `this.location_coordinate` before accessing `this.location_coordinate.latitude`